# Tabbar controller with navigation controller in a single application

Tags: iphone

I have created an empty application and then added a window to it(made a window based application).

Then i added tabbarcontroller to it and navigation controller inside the tabbarcontroller. I have added nib files to my application for each tabs and given the nib names to viewcontrollers.Then i added a button to one of the nib file ,then application is crashing and giving error like -

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnNext.'

-----i have connected the iboutlet of buttons too.then why this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the IBOutlets are not wired correctly. One common example is if you were to wire an IBOutlet in Interface Builder, but then delete the corresponding property in the corresponding class (where the IBOutlet was defined).  Obviousily that's a mistake when that happens, but unfortunately Xcode will not give you a compile time error, and instead gives you this vague runtime error.  Take a look at ALL IBOutlets in the relevant Interface Builder files and make sure they match up correctly to the IBOutlets in the header files (both in type and presence).

Comment: Actually i am trying with an example so only one button is there.
in the .h file i have given
    UIButton *btnNext;

property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet  UIButton *btnNext;
end

and in implementation file
synthesize  btnNext;

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add navigation controller to tab and inside the navigation controller in (view controller) you need to put the class name of view controller. Hope this [link](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/06/tab-bars-and-navigation-bars-t.html) will also help you.

Comment: Now error has gone but it is loading only window not the tabbar and views

Comment: you need to add tabbar to app delegate like [self.window addSubView:tabBarController.view];